# Launch external app in first window of split screen

Tags: android, multi-window, split-screen

I run my two apps in Split Screen mode. First app A, second app B. Now when I start external activity like Google Maps from app A, it always open it in second screen on top of app B. I want it to open on first screen, on top of app A. I even tried `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT`, it doesn't help.

```
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
              Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=$latitude,$longitude"))
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT)
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, MAP_NAVIG_RC)
```

In short, Android always open external activity in Second screen of split screen. How can I launch it in First screen?

Comment: were you able to find a way to do this ?